# Obtener todos los productos de unas determinadas categorías en Mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo dos esquemas de Mongoose que resumidos con lo importante son algo asi:

Esquema de producto:

- _id
- Nombre
- Referencia a Categoria

Y el esquema de Categoria es:

- _id
- Nombre

Y lo que quiero es obtenerme todos los productos de las categorías enviadas por parámetros en una llamada de API. Estuve probando algunas cosas pero no me funciono y lo deje algo así:

```
let getProductsByCategory = (req, res) => {
    let query = { estado: true };
    let { categorias } = req.query;
    Producto.find({categoria: 'Cerveza'}, '_id codigo descripcion nombre precioCosto precioVenta categoria marca estado')
        .sort({nombre: 'asc'})
        .populate('categoria', '_id nombre')
        .populate('marca', '_id nombre')
        .exec((err, productos) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: err
                });
            }
            if (!productos) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'No se encontraron productos.'
                    }
                });
            }

            res.json({
                ok: true,
                cantidad: productos.length,
                entidadResultante: productos
            });
        })
}
```

Lo que querría sería en esa variable `categorias` donde tiene un array de nombres de categorías buscar todos los productos en el cual categoria.nombre coincida con alguno del array. Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar hacer algo así:

```
const categorias = ["cervezas", "vinos"]; //Lo que obtienes de req.query
Producto.find({"categoria.name": { $in: [categorias] })
```

Aquí tienes mas: [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) o tambien puedes usar [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) para búsquedas mas complejas.

Comment: Justo estaba probando hacer algo como dijiste, iba a hacer: 
``let { categorias } = req.query;
    Producto.find({categoria: {$in: categorias}}`` Si funciona esto te pongo como mejor rta.

Comment: No me estaría funcionando @Ale, me devuelve true pero con ningun documento adentro. Probe como dijiste y como dije yo y tambien como puse yo y cambiando a "categoria.nombre" y ninguna de las 3 funciono. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Tenes un `_id` (ObjectId) de categorias en tus productos? (la referencia a la categoria)
Tal vez podrias hacer un `aggregate`